# display element in hover

Tags: html, css

I want my element `<a>` to be hidden and when hover within the div, display will be available.

I want my element `<a>` to have a hover effect that it will be available upon hover.

```html
<div class="task-list">
  <ul>
    {% for i in list %}

    <li class="todo-listing">
      <div class="div-for-listing">
        <form class="form-list" action="{{url_for('to_do_list')}}" method="post">
          <input class="checkbox-list" type="checkbox" id=list-{{i.id}} name=list-{{i.id}} value="ongoing" onclick="toggle_check()">
          <label class="todo-listing-data" for=list-{{i.id}}> {{i.task}}</label>
          <a href=""></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-xmark" id="delete-button"></i></a>
          <br>
        </form>
      </div>


    </li>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change the html to pure HTML with for example 3 LIs and add relevant HTML, CSS (and JS). This is NOT a python question. We want a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by targeting the `:hover` pseudo-class, here I've chosen the parent `<div>`, `.div-for-listing`

```css
.div-for-listing a {
  display: none
}

.div-for-listing:hover a {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="task-list">
  <ul>
    {% for i in list %}

    <li class="todo-listing">
      <div class="div-for-listing">
        <form class="form-list" action="{{url_for('to_do_list')}}" method="post">
          <input class="checkbox-list" type="checkbox" id=list-{{i.id}} name=list-{{i.id}} value="ongoing" onclick="toggle_check()">
          <label class="todo-listing-data" for=list-{{i.id}}> {{i.task}}</label>
          <a href="">Link</a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-xmark" id="delete-button"></i></a>
          <br>
        </form>
      </div>


    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```